# highlight HTML line if cursor is near

Tags: html, css

I bet my question already exist but I do not know how to phrase it. I got several HTML lines, which I want to highlight (change color etc.) on mouseover. The lines itself is 2-3px width, which challenging users to select the correct line.

How could I highlight a line if the mouse is also close to a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add padding to your text.

```css
p{
  padding: 40px;
}
p:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
p:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>The :hover selector style links on mouse-over.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it refers to hovering only. My problem is different, your text for example should be also highlighted, if the cursor is close to the text too.

Comment: Add padding to the paragraph.

Comment: @ICoded But you wrote " I got several HTML lines, which I want to highlight (change color etc.) **on mouseover**". Don't be moving goalposts now.

Comment: @Dai still you should read the full question to get the whole context. Otherwise none conversation makes any sense if you only pick single sentences out of it.